# I want to link multiple domains to one bucket with gcs

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I want to link multiple domains to one bucket with gcs

However, in an official document, the bucket name will be the domain as it is, so it seems that you can not associate multiple domains.

Do not you know someone?

Answer (score 1):

GCS does not support this directly. Instead, to accomplish this, you'd likely need to make use of Google Cloud Load Balancing with your GCS bucket as a backing store. With it, you can obtain a dedicated, static IP address which you can map several domains to, and it also allows you to map static and dynamic content under the same domain, and it allows you to swap out which bucket is being served at the same path. The main downside to it is added complexity and cost.